# Python- group lines by first two words

Tags: python

I want to group a file by the first two words in the file (and then re-arrange and print)

I want do

```
   lines=file.readlines()
   i=0
   for line in lines:
    word1=line.split()[0]
    word2=line.split()[1]
    if word1==lines[i+1].split()[0] and word1==lines[i-1].split()[0] :
        if word2=lines[i-1].split()[1] and word2==lines[i--1].split()[0]:
              print line
    else:
       print "***new block of lines \n***"
```

This is a very poor solution though because it doesnt work for first or last line and doesn't work very well overall. better solution are really appreciated

Comment: In order to understand what you're asking I need to decrypt your code and it's bad code... You should provide an example of such a file and what is the requested output. BTW what is `i` used for ? printing line `-1` ?

Comment: i was being used to access next line and previous line

Comment: And which line would `lines[i-1].split()[0]` return when `i=0` ? Where do you increment `i` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to group consecutive lines that share the first two words in a file, that's a use case for `itertools.groupby`, eg:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('somefile') as fin:
    lines = ((line.split(None, 2)[:2], line) for line in fin if line.strip())
    for k, g in groupby(lines, lambda L: L[0]):
        lines = [el[1] for el in g]
```

Here `k` is the grouping key (up to first two words) and `lines` will be the lines from the file that share that key.

Example `somefile` input:

```
one two three four five
one two five six seven
three four something
three four something else
one two start of new one two block
```

Result of `print k, lines`:

```
['one', 'two'] ['one two three four five\n', 'one two five six seven\n']
['three', 'four'] ['three four something\n', 'three four something else\n']
['one', 'two'] ['one two start of new one two block\n']
```

To exclude the first two words from the `line`, use:

```
with open('somefile') as fin:
    lines = (line.split(None, 2) for line in fin if line.strip())
    for k, g in groupby(lines, lambda L: L[:2]):
        lines = [el[2] for el in g]
```

Comment: lets say i wanted to print something everytime a new group of lines (new group of first two words) occured, how would i do that?

Comment: @Illusionist each iteration of the `for k, g`... loop is the start of a new group

Comment: if i want to not print the first two words in the line so that the output is ['one', 'two'] [' three four five\n', 'five six seven\n'] , how do i do that?  I tried     newlines = ((line.split()[2:], line) for line in lines  and it gave me an error

Comment: @Illusionist updated to show how to do that... Is it worthy of an accept yet? :p

Answer (score 1):

This should probably work but I can't be sure without an example file and desired output sample.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d= defaultdict(list)
for line in text:
    try: 
        first, second =  line.split(' ', 2)[:2]
        first_two = '.'.join((first, second)).lower() 
        d[first_two].append(line) 
    except ValueError: 
        #or do something else with lines less than 2 words long here
        pass 

for first_two, lines in d.items(): 

    print("first two: %s" %(first_two.split("."), )) 
    for line in lines: 
        print(line) 
    print("         -----       ")
```

Sample Input:

```
['one two three for five six',
 'three four five',
 'three nine seven eight',
 'three four five six seven',
 'one two nine eleven ']
```

Sample Output:

```
first two: ['three', 'nine']
three nine seven eight
         -----       
first two: ['one', 'two']
one two three for five six
one two nine eleven 
         -----       
first two: ['three', 'four']
three four five
three four five six seven
```

Comment: Despite it being a bare `except` which is tremendously bad practice - how do you even expect it to throw in the case there aren't two words?

Comment: @JonClements  because `line.split(' ')[:2]` will give an index error.

Comment: No it won't - try it: `'nospaces'.split(' ')[:2]`

Comment: If you did instead: `first, second, rest = line.split(' ', 2)` then `d[first, second].append(line)` and caught `ValueError` specifically, that's what I think you're after...

Comment: @JonClements good catch. I don't think you want `rest` because then it will fail on a two word line.

Comment: Now `'.'.join(first, second)` will throw a `TypeError`... and yeah re `rest`... it depends if *only* two word lines are to be deemed valid or not I guess...

Comment: And, since you know you only want the first two then you can specify the max number of splits so Python doesn't have to parse the entire string and create more list elements than necessary, eg: `line.split(' ', 2)[:2]`

Answer (score 1):

This should do.

```
# f > File Pointer
lines = f.readlines()
x, y = lines[0].split(' ')[:2]
def chk_match(z, firstWord ,secondWord):
    t = z.split(' ')
    if len(t)>=2:
        if firstWord == t[0] and secondWord == t[1]:
            return 1
    return 0
print [z for z in lines if chk_match(z,x,y) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [91]: simple_text = ['one two three for five six',
    ...:  'three four five',
    ...:  'three nine seven eight',
    ...:  'three four five six seven',
    ...:  'one two nine eleven ']

In [92]: result = {}

In [93]: for line in simple_text:
    ...:     result.setdefault(tuple(line.split()[:2]), [])
    ...:     result[tuple(line.split()[:2])].append(line)
    ...:     

In [94]: for k in result:
    ...:     print k , result[k]
    ...:     
('three', 'nine') ['three nine seven eight']
('one', 'two') ['one two three for five six', 'one two nine eleven ']
('three', 'four') ['three four five', 'three four five six seven']
```

if you want ordering; then you use `OrderedDict` as

```
In [95]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [96]: result = OrderedDict()

In [97]: for line in simple_text:
    ...:     result.setdefault(tuple(line.split()[:2]), [])
    ...:     result[tuple(line.split()[:2])].append(line)
    ...:     

In [98]: for k in result:
    ...:     print k , result[k]
    ...:     
('one', 'two') ['one two three for five six', 'one two nine eleven ']
('three', 'four') ['three four five', 'three four five six seven']
('three', 'nine') ['three nine seven eight']
```