# File parsing python recursive

Tags: python

I am learning python.

I have a file like this

```
str1 str2 str3 str4
str1 str2 str7 str8
***
str9 str10 str12 str13
str9 str10 str16 str17
****
str 18 str19 str20 str21 
***
```

and so on.

I want to change it to this format->

```
str1
str2 str3 str4
str2 str7 str8

str9
str10 str12 str13
str10 str16 str17

str 18
str19 str20 str21
```

so if the first 2 words are common between 2 lines, arrange the lines together and remove the first word to a separate line.
This should be changeable recursively but i can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Is that meant to be `str18` ?

Comment: Are the `***` actually present in the file?

Comment: What have you tried?  Why didn't it work?  Where does recursion actually come in to it?

Comment: the string number doesnt matter joe, *** can be present or i can strip it.

Comment: lguanaut i want to do it recursively and can't figure it out. I tried getting next line and previous line and comparing it but it didn't work out

Comment: @Illusionist any reason you can't adapt my previous answer to your question? This isn't something you want to be doing recursively...

Comment: i can try that jon, it seemed like a good target for recursion .. thanks

Comment: @Illusionist just change it to take the first word only (instead of the first two) and strip out your `***` lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a slight modification to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28759802 ...

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    stripped_lines = (line.rstrip('*\n') for line in fin)
    split_lines = (line.split(None, 1) for line in stripped_lines if line)
    for k, g in groupby(split_lines, lambda L: L[0]):
        fout.write('{}\n{}\n\n'.format(k, '\n'.join(el[1] for el in g)))
```

Comment: You will end up with str and 18 on different lines, unless that is a type that is why I used `line.rsplit(None,3)` but that will also fail if there are spaces somewhere else in the values.

Comment: @Padraic I'm kinda assuming it's a typo... The OP hasn't responded with clarification to my comment yet though :)

Comment: well if it is at least their typo's are consistent :)

Comment: Not sure what to do with the stray newlines at the  end though.

Comment: @Padraic think that can be left to the OP to work out *exactly* how they want it formatted

Answer (score 1):

Use an OrderedDict storing last three strings as the values and the first as the key, then write the keys and values at the end.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict()

with open("words.txt") as f,open("fixed.txt","w") as out:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith("*"):
            spl = line.split(None,1)
            od.setdefault(spl[0],[])
            od[spl[0]].append(spl[1:])
    for k, v in od.items():
        out.write("{}\n{}\n".format(k,"".join(" ".join(row) for row in v)))
```